# Get time difference in milliseconds between JVM and UTC

Tags: java, kotlin, time, timezone, dst

I am having an exceedingly hard time trying to figure out what seems to be a simple problem.

I would like to calculate the difference (offset?) in milliseconds between the UTC instant and the JVM instant (i.e. specific to the machine running the code).

I have tried the following initializations (sorry, this is in Kotlin, not Java):

```
// 1
val difference = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())

// 2
val difference = ZoneId.systemDefault().rules.getOffset(Instant.EPOCH).totalSeconds * 1000

// 3
val difference = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).offset.totalSeconds * 1000
```

To be more specific: I am running this on my Mac on the US west coast today (Feb 22, 2024 -- i.e. during Daylight Savings). All 3 initializations produce `-28800000` (i.e. timezone-based) when I am looking for an initialization that will produce `-25200000` (i.e. DST-sensitive / instant-based).

What am I doing wrong here?

I would like the solution to be timezone/machine agnostic (i.e. I could run this code on any machine around the world without any specific input like a string timezone).

EDIT:

As @Louis Wasserman pointed out, my expectation that the initializations would produce `-25200000` is incorrect as the current time difference is in fact `-28800000`.

My incorrect expectation is due to the fact I had written the following test:

```
@Test
fun timeStrToEpochMillis_invariantValidation_happyPaths() {
    // Arrange
    val testTimeStr = "2023-06-13 20:21:46"

    // Act
    val result = timeStrToEpochMillis(testTimeStr)

    // Assert
    assertEquals(1686687706000, result)
}
```

For the below function:

```
fun timeStrToEpochMillis(timeStr: String): Long {
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    return df.parse(timeStr).time
}
```

When I ran the above test in a container, whose default time zone is UTC, the test would pass. However, when running the above test on my local machine, whose default time zone is Pacific, the test would fail.

I overlooked that the difference ought to be based on the test string, like so:

```
@Test
fun timeStrToEpochMillis_invariantValidation_happyPaths() {
    // Arrange
    val testTimeStr = "2023-06-13 20:21:46"

    // Act
    val result = timeStrToEpochMillis(testTimeStr)
    val diff = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(result)

    // Assert
    assertEquals(1686687706000 + diff, result)
}
```

Thanks again to @Louis Wasserman for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: You said "US west coast today (Feb 22, 2024 -- i.e. during Daylight Savings)". Incorrect. In February 2024, the time zone `America/Los_Angeles` is in standard time, not Daylight Saving Time (DST). The offset in that month is -08:00, eight hours behind UTC.

Comment: "between the UTC instant and the JVM instant (i.e. specific to the machine running the code)." Perhaps that is a poor choice of words, but it is confusing. A `java.time.Instant` is always framed in terms of zero offset from UTC. If that is not what you meant, edit to re-word.

Comment: Your Question is quite confusing. Are you trying to calculate time elapsed between two points on the timeline? Or are you trying to access the offset in effect for a time zone?

Comment: Tip: Do not mix the terribly flawed legacy classes such as `SimpleDateFormat` with their modern replacements, the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. **Use only *java.time* classes.**

Comment: For getting the JVM’s default time zone’s *current* offset from UTC in milliseconds, `//3` is the preferred and the correct option. Since the offset changes sometimes, you can use `// 2` for the offset at another time, passing the appropriate instant where your current code has `Instant.EPOCH`. Avoid `// 1`since the `TimeZone` class had design issues and is long outdated.

Comment: No need to add the offset yourself. It’s all automatic. To convert your string to milliseconds since the epoch first define `val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT)`. Then get the millisecond count from `LocalDateTime.parse("2023-06-13 20:21:46", formatter) .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) .toInstant() .toEpochMilli()`. Or may use `ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")` for the `ZoneId` of the west coast of the USA (assuming not Alaska). Result is 1 686 712 906 000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently Daylight Savings Time on the US West Coast.  The time zone America/Los_Angeles, used by the US West Coast, *is* currently 28800000 milliseconds from UTC.

The JVM is correct here.

You later commented:

> My question is missing some context: I am trying to apply this logic to a specific date time string ("2023-06-13 20:21:46"), which is in Daylight Savings

You have found `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).offset)`: use instead `ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime, ZoneId)`, with that `LocalDateTime`.

Comment:  you're absolutely right. My question is missing some context: I am trying to apply this logic to a specific date time string ("2023-06-13 20:21:46"), which is in Daylight Savings... what an annoying oversight. I think I know how to correct my problem, and I will update this post accordingly. Thank you for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: You have found `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).offset)`: use instead [`ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime, ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneId-), with that `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Thanks Louis -- I opted to use another initialization, but I get the idea of your suggestion above. I edited my question with additional context; feel free to modify your answer to address that portion as well.